# How can a bond price that follows an Ito process possably have value 1 at maturity?

Tags: fixed-income, bond

Consider the HJM model for instance. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heath%E2%80%93Jarrow%E2%80%93Morton_framework#Mathematical_formulation), the price $P(t,T)$ of a ZCB at time $t$ with maturity time $T$ is of the form

$$
{\displaystyle {\frac {dP(t,T)}{P(t,T)}}=\mu\left(t,T\right)dt-{{\sigma }}(t,T)dW_{t}}.
$$

How can this possibly force $P(T,T)=1$? It's said that $\mu\left(t,T\right)$ is an adapted process (wrt to $t$), so it may depend on $P(t,T)$. I would think it must, in order to steer the process back to 1 at $T$.

But then under the risk-neutral measure $\mathbb{Q}$, of course $\mu\left(t,T\right)=0$ , then I can't possibly see how $P(T,T)=1$ can hold. We would need $\sigma(t,T)\to 0$ as $t\to T$, but that would seems to slow the volatility to 0 freezing the process at the value just before time $T$ possibly not 1. I don't see how it can possibly be steered back to 1 without a drift term.

Comment: Under $\mathbb Q$ the correct drift is $r(t)\,dt$ and not zero. You see $P(T,T)=1$ from $P(t,T)=\mathbb E[\exp(-\int_t^Tr(s)\,ds)|{\cal F}_t]$ rather than from that SDE. Every textbook covering the HJM approach has those derivations.

Comment: Oh yeah. this is a dumb question. I'm gonna delete in a sec.

Comment: It is not dumb but not very new either.